# Web check script hangs on second run

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to connect to Google for a quick check of the Internet availability and host response. If the check returns 200, move on to next script.

The script below works initially. However, when I try multiple times, specifically after 2 runs, PowerShell hangs and doesn't move forward.
If I restart PowerShell and run the script, it runs OK for two times then it hangs again.

I am planning to put this in the Scheduler and run it regularly.
What am I missing here? Can anyone of you advise?

```
# Once connection gets established, quick status test
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.google.com")
try {
  $response = $request.GetResponse()
} catch {
  if ($error) {
    # write some error on the log
  }
}

# if response returns 200, proceed next step, else create critical log
if ($response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 200) {
  & ./hostCheck.ps1 ; # Start host Check
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does it get stuck? When getting a response from the web, or when running `hostCheck.ps1`?

Comment: hi, it seems it is getting stuck $response = $request.GetResponse() this part.  Is there a way i can clean the connection after the process?

Comment: What does $response.Close() exactly do? Does it clear the GetResponse? So If there is any loop to connect, I have to basically do GetResponse() again?

Comment: I added $response.Close() at the end and it doesn't get stuck anymore. So far I have ran it for 6 times and still working fine. So I guess it resolved. Thanks for your time to look into this.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.close.aspx). You should also call [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928381.aspx) to release the resources allocated by the response object.